# Validating input fields form vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, validation

I wonder how can I run the emit in the App.vue file if all of the input fields of a multistep form are filled? I've written the logic but I can't get the final block displayed in the end when all of the fields are filled.

https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-jasper-teh1im?file=/src/components/Button.vue

```js
<template>
  <button class="btn" @click="submit">Submit</button>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    submit() {
      if (
        this.firstName !== "" &&
        this.lastName !== "" &&
        this.paymentAmount !== "" &&
        this.accountNumber !== ""
      ) {
        this.$emit("final");
      } else {
        alert("please fill the required fields");
      }
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.btn {
  padding: 10px 30px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: variables are scoped to the component they're used in unless you pass them down as props or emit them up to a parent (or use some global store).  looking at just the component code you've included here, where does `this.firstName`, `this.lastName`, etc. come from?  You've not passed them in from anywhere. Think of components as their own isolated bubbles of code.  If you need to pass data between them you need to come up with the correct strategy to do so.  Please study the concept of [props](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/component-basics.html#passing-props) in Vue, it will help you!

Comment: Ideally, Submit button component should be in `App.vue` instead of separate `Step1` and `Step2` components  as per the requirement you have. And you have to emit the forms data to `App.vue` for the form field validations.

Comment: BTW I've added also some codesandbox link, thanks )

Comment: Like I said, you can do what you want with props.  Props are basic Vue functionality. I do not mean to be rude but if you struggle with the basics I recommend any of the great Vue tutorials out there with projects you can code-along with. They will teach you all the fundamentals of Vue you can use to then code your own project. The official docs are also a great learning tool. You should at least have the fundamentals down and have fully reviewed the Vue docs before asking a question on Stack Overflow. I'm just trying to teach you how to fish rather than fish for you.